# What is the definition of a polytope in terms of set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, polytopes

I know that the set definition of a polytope $P^+_f$ associated with a polymatroid function f is:

$$ P^+_f = \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^V_+ : y(A) \leq f(A), \forall A \subseteq V\}$$

where $y(A) = \sum_{i \in A } y_i$ denotes the component sum using the indices in $A$.

However, what is the general definition of a polytope in terms of set theory?

I know how polytopes look in general because I understand intuitively how polygons (polytopes in 2D) and polyhedra (polytopes in 3D) look like, but I am unsure how to express that intuition in rigorous and precise set theory. Anyone know how? Plus wikipedia doesn't seem that helpful in that regard :(

Comment: Have you perused the discussion of possible definitions in the [Wikipedia article on polytopes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope)? There are several approaches, some of them differing in whether you allow non-convex or self-intersecting polytopes.

Comment: I see, that makes more sense why it was hard to define one definition.

Comment: @HenningMakholm maybe a better question to ask is...which set theoretic definition does a polymatroidal polytope fits...